# Can someone explain me this DAX Expression?

Tags: powerbi, dax

```
Daily Reimbursement Rates =
CALCULATE (
    CONCATENATEX (
        VALUES ( f_Census[DailyReimbursement] ),
        FORMAT ( f_Census[DailyReimbursement], "$0.00" ),
        ", "
    )
)
```

Comment: You can remove "CALCULATE" from the formula, it's unnecessary here.

Answer (score 1):

It will take all values in [DailyReimbursment] format it so that the value is in USD with 2 decimals and concatenate them with ", " in-between.

Table:

[image]

Measure:

```
Rate = 
CALCULATE(
    CONCATENATEX(
        VALUES(Data[Value]);
        FORMAT('Data'[Value]; "$0.00");
        ", "
    )
)
```

Result:

[image]

Read more about CONCATENATEX here: [MicrosoftDocs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/concatenatex-function-dax)